# What are Tied Events in the context of Cox-Regression?

Tags: survival

As my topic suggests, can someone explain me what tied events actually are?

I just read that there are different algoriths of handling ties differently in Cox-Regression, but so for I did not understand what "tied event" data actually is.

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 3):

Tied events are simply when two events occur at the exact same recorded time.

For example, if a study measures time until remission in months and subjects 1 and 2 both experienced remission at month 2, then their event times are tied.

This creates a small issue for the canonical Cox regression model, as it uses the ranks of event times to fit the model. However, this is not too difficult to handle and there are several easy ways to fix it up.

Comment: what are ways to deal with tied events in cox regression?

Comment: @mnky9800n: I don't know all of the methods, but a cheap solution is simply to break them at random

Answer (score 2):

The tied events are the parameters that the different variables contain at the same time occasion.

There are about 5 methods to handle the tied events in Cox regression. Berslow, Efron, Exact, distinct, and random.
according to http://soep.ue.poznan.pl/jdownloads/Wszystkie%20numery/Rok%202014/06_borucka.pdf
the erfron method performes better in terms of time, fit statistics, and  differences in parameters estimates.